# Bar chart: use color cycle for edgecolor

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I want a bar chart with edge colors but no fills. This I can get with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.bar(1, 1, color='None', edgecolor='purple')
axes.bar(2, 2, color='None', edgecolor='red')
```

**However**, I want the edge colors to be coming from the axes' default color_cycle. I couldn't find any public property. The only thing that works is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.bar(1, 1, color='None', edgecolor=axes._get_lines.get_next_color())
axes.bar(2, 2, color='None', edgecolor=axes._get_lines.get_next_color())
```

Which feels incredibly hacky. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're proposing is outlandish.
If you wanted, you get a copy of the iterator instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
cycler = axes._get_lines.prop_cycler
axes.bar(1, 1, color='None', edgecolor=next(cycler)['color'])
axes.bar(2, 2, color='None', edgecolor=next(cycler)['color'])
```

Or, if this feels less "hackish" to you, get the cycler from the rcParams:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

cycler = itertools.cycle(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.bar(1, 1, color='None', edgecolor=next(cycler)['color'])
axes.bar(2, 2, color='None', edgecolor=next(cycler)['color'])
```